# conda version unchanged after updating

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to update anaconda on wsl2 platform. The current version for my conda is

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.14.0
```

and I have tried using `conda update anaconda`. The `stdout` seems successful:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/lloyd/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - anaconda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    constantly-23.10.4         |   py39h06a4308_0          26 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:          26 KB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  constantly         pkgs/main/noarch::constantly-15.1.0-p~ --> pkgs/main/linux-64::constantly-23.10.4-py39h06a4308_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
constantly-23.10.4   | 26 KB     | ############################################################################# | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
```

When I re-check the conda version, it shows 4.14.0 as it was.
What could the problem be? I'd appreciate suggestions of any kind. Thanks!

Update:
Thanks to @FlyingTeller and @AKX, actually I have also used `conda update conda` but the problem remains. Here I post the output of updating conda:

```
$ conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Retrieving notices: ...working... done
```

But the version is still 4.14.0.

Comment: That result shows a package called `constantly` being updated...?

Comment: yeah I think so……that's because I have tried `conda update anaconda` a few times, and I believe other packages that needed to be updated have been updated.

Comment: you want `conda update conda`

Comment: Updating `conda` is a different thing than upgrading `anaconda`; see https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/update-version/#updating-from-older-versions

Comment: Thanks @FlyingTeller and @AKX, I have updated the output of `conda update conda`. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: There is something in the environment constraining `conda` from being updated. Try insisting on a minimum version, e.g., `conda install -n base 'conda>=23'`, this will at least force Conda to explain itself.

Comment: Thanks @merv! I have successfully updated to 23.5.2 following your suggestion. Thanks again!